# Symfony merge multipe emails in one

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I am using Symfony 3 with swiftmailer.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to merge multiple emails in one. So instead user take 3 emails take 1 email with the 3 emails merged inside. This way I will avoid spamming user.

I have read about spooling but spooling don't merge, instead send emails after some time, depending on the cronjob you will use.

So is there an easy way or bundle for this or have to create this on my own?

Comment: Do you mean include multiple emails in the `To:` field using Swiftmailer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the content of multiple emails into one email? This sounds like you would need something custom. For example you could store the emails to be sent but not send them, and run a cronjob to send all the pending content as one e-mail. I'm not sure why you would need this though - maybe you'd be better off considering when and why you're sending e-mails.

Edit: from comments the goal is to merge multiple notifications into one e-mail. In this case it might be more understandable (for someone new looking at the code) if there was a `notifications` entity and a cronjob command that just created an e-mail with all the pending notifications and sent it.

Comment: The objective is not to spam user sending every notification in each own email but instead group all notifications he should get in one. Imagine doing various things in a portal and get 10 emails that you did something. Instead I want to get 1 email listing the 10 things you did.

It's like what monolog does I think by grouping logs and send them in one email instead spamming you.

Comment: Sounds like you could just change your logic a bit, maybe create a pending notifications table, then use a cronjob to send all pending ones every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the not sending multiple emails to a user, you should not use `Swiftmailer` in that case.
Instead of creating an email each time you want to notify the you should create and store an information in the database.
Then you have to implement a command to fetch all notifications for a user and put them in one email - for that you can use `Swiftmailer`.